# What compilers are included in Xcode Command Line tools?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction

Is there a way to check this? I know llvm is one of the compilers in Xcode, I think GCC also?? Is this correct? is there a definitive way to know?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Xcode 4 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/developertools/rn-xcode/xc4_release_notes/xc4_release_notes.html):

> DEPRECATED: LLVM-GCC compiler and GDB debugger.
>   Xcode 4.6 is the last release to include the LLVM-GCC compiler and the GDB debugger.

And

> GCC 4.0 has been removed from Xcode 4. If your project has an explicit
>   Compiler Version of gcc 4.0, you need to change it in order to build
>   with Xcode 4.

Xcode 5 comes "only" with the LLVM compiler suite, including "clang" and "clang++".